# Using OpenCV's PCACompute function

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to implement facial recognition with eigenfaces, using OpenCV for Android.

I have a set of training images, which are all 100x100 pixel greyscale images. I am currently using Highgui.imread to read in these images, so each image is a Mat with a width  and height of 100. I'm trying to use the Core.PCACompute function to find principal components of this set of images.

```
public static void PCACompute(Mat data, Mat mean, Mat eigenvectors, int maxComponents)
```

So my question is: what dimensions does the first argument (Mat data) need to have? Is it possible to pass it a set of multiple images even though data is only a single Mat?

Or am I doing it wrong, and this is not the correct function to use for eigenfaces? One tutorial I have seen uses a C++ function called cvCalcEigenObjects, but I am not able to find the equivalent Java method...

Answer (score 1):

**The function expects a single Mat** as input. But you can pass data [like this](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/java/android_test/src/org/opencv/test/core/CoreTest.java):

```
1711        public void testPCAComputeMatMatMat() {
1712            Mat data = new Mat(3, 4, CvType.CV_32F) {
1713                {
1714                    put(0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 4);
1715                    put(1, 0, 2, 4, 4, 8);
1716                    put(2, 0, 3, 6, 6, 12);
1717                }
1718            };
1719            Mat mean = new Mat();
1720            Mat vectors = new Mat();
1721    
1722            Core.PCACompute(data, mean, vectors);
1723    
1724            Mat mean_truth = new Mat(1, 4, CvType.CV_32F) {
1725                {
1726                    put(0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 8);
1727                }
1728            };
1729            Mat vectors_truth = new Mat(3, 4, CvType.CV_32F, new Scalar(0)) {
1730                {
1731                    put(0, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.8);
1732                }
1733            };
1734            assertMatEqual(mean_truth, mean, EPS);
1735            assertMatEqual(vectors_truth, vectors, EPS);
1736        }
```

To start playing with face recognition I suggest this [doc](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceRecognition), as it explains [what PCA does](http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_4/page_2.html).

And [this link](http://pebibyte.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/simple-face-recognition-using-opencv/) provides some info and source code for doing simple face recognition using images for training.

Comment: In the Cognotics article that you linked (part 5, page 4), they call cvCalcEigenObjects with the arguments nTrainFaces and faceImgArr. faceImgArr is an array of nTrainFaces images.  In the context of eigenfaces, would the Mat data object in your code represent three face images?