# How can I perform face recognition using an eigenfaces value in OpenCV?

Tags: android, opencv, pca, eigenvector, eigenvalue

After using OpenCV's `PCACompute` function as shown below, I have a `Mat` representing mean and a `Mat` of eigenvectors.

```
org.opencv.core.Core.PCACompute(datiOriginali,mean, eigenvectors,0);
```

`datiOriginali` is my input `Mat`, `mean` is the mean value `Mat` and `eigenvectors` is the eigenvectors `Mat`.

From there, I used PCAProject thus:

```
org.opencv.core.Core.PCAProject(datiOriginali, mean,eigenvectors , res);
```

`datiOriginali` is always the input `Mat`, `mean` and `eigenvectors` are the same as were calculated in `PCACompute` and `res` is the output `Mat`.

How can I perform face recognition using an eigenfaces value? I don't know how to calculate the Euclidean distance between a training image calculated as shown above and a new image.

Comment: I'm not even going to read that...

Comment: What Bali C???  
Sorry but i don't understand....

Comment: I don't know anything about OpenCV (I only came by because someone marked this question as needing cleanup) but this question looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520139/using-opencvs-pcacompute-function